# defining an instance vs using class constraints

Tags: haskell

I'm going through [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#recursive-data-structures)

and am on the chapter that discusses typeclasses. There is this snippet:

```
class (Eq a) => Num a where
```

I understood this as a class constraint being imposed on the `Num` class, forcing it to act as an equatable class. My question is, why wasn't `Num` implemented as an instance of `Eq`? Like this:

```
instance Eq Num where
... stuff
```

Defining an instance seems like a cleaner way to do this, but maybe I'm missing something. Can someone please explain the difference to me?

Comment: I think you're getting confused between type and type class. Only a type, not another type class, can be made an instance of a type class. `instance Eq Num where ...` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Jubobs Isnt `Num` in this case a type that extends `Eq`?

Comment: Excerpt from LYAH:

You can also make typeclasses that are subclasses of other typeclasses. The class declaration for Num is a bit long, but here's the first part:

    `class (Eq a) => Num a where  `

Comment: `Num` is a type class (a subclass of `Eq`), not a type.

Comment: @Jubobs But suppose it wasn't. What if I wanted to define Num'? What would the difference be?

Comment: @dopatraman How will you define `Num` as a type ? Typeclass are a way of providing ad hoc polymorphism. You cannot achieve that by creating a type.

Comment: not sure i understand what you mean by ad hoc polymorphism. My understanding was that `Num` could extend `Eq` to build abstraction and to avoid redundancy in code. Is that not true?

Comment: @dopatraman ad hoc polymorphism provides overloading. You can use the same functions on different types (for whom you have provided instances). Like `+` function can be used on `Int`, `Float`, `Double` etc. What `class (Eq a) => Num a where` says is that for a type to be of `Num` instance it should already have an instance on `Eq` typeclass.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about how using `instance` would not serve the same purpose?

Comment: `Num` is _not_ a type.  `Num` is a type class which other types, like `Int`, might implement.  You can't have a value of type `Num`, but you can have a value of type `Int`.

Answer (score 7):

Let's pronounce a couple of these Haskell declarations in English; perhaps that will clarify a few things. I'll give the Haskell declaration first, and an English transliteration afterwards.

```
class Eq a where (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

There is a set of types. We name this set `Eq`. If `a` is a type in this set, then we can compare two values of that type for equality using a function named `(==)`.

```
data Brillant = T | F | FileNotFound
instance Eq Brillant where
    T == T = True
    F == F = True
    FileNotFound == FileNotFound = True
    _ == _ = False
```

There is a type named `Brillant`. It has constructors `T`, `F`, and `FileNotFound`. The `Brillant` type is an element of the `Eq` set. Two terms of type `Brillant` can be compared for equality by checking whether they use the same constructor.

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
instance Eq a => Eq (Maybe a) where
    Nothing == Nothing = True
    Just v == Just v' = v == v'
```

Whenever we have a type `a`, there is another type `Maybe a`. If `a` is an element of the `Eq` set, then `Maybe a` is an element of the `Eq` set.

```
class Eq a => Num a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
```

There is a set of types. We name this set `Num`. If `a` is a type in this set, then `a` is also in the set `Eq` (or, in other words, `Num` is a subset of `Eq`). If `a` is a type in the `Num` set, then we can add two values of this type and get a third using the `(+)` function.

If the following declaration were valid Haskell, here's what it would mean:

```
instance Eq Num where -- ...
```

The set named `Num` of types is an element of the set named `Eq` of types.

Now let's compare the last two, namely, `class Eq a => Num a` and `instance Eq Num`. The former says that members of the `Num` set are also members of the `Eq` set, while the latter says that the `Num` set itself is a member of the `Eq` set. Hopefully the latter sets off some kind of alarm bell in your head. Since we said `Eq` is a set of types, all members of that set should be types. But we also said `Num` is a set of types, not a type; so it can't be a member.

It can make sense to talk about sets of sets of types -- that is, classes whose instances are other classes -- but neither `Eq` nor `Num` do that. So it would not be correct to claim that `Num` is an instance of `Eq`.

Comment: According to your example, type `Brilliant` is a member of set `Eq`. Why isnt type `Num` also a member of `Eq`?

Comment: @dopatraman As discussed in my answer: `Num` is a set of types (and therefore not, itself, a type); since `Num` is not a type, it _cannot_ be a member of any set of types. `Eq` is a set of types, so `Num` cannot be a member of `Eq`.

Comment: Suppose `Num` was not a pre defined Haskell type. Say it was `Num'` or some such thing. Couldnt it be true that `Num'` is a member of `Eq`? Then say that `Num'` has all the properties of a member of `Num`, isnt it true that `instance Eq Num'` ?

Comment: @dopatraman You can certainly define a new type named `Num'` and make it an instance of the `Eq` class. What you cannot do is define a new class named `Num'` and make it an instance of the `Eq` class. Classes and types are _fundamentally different_ things (and the Haskell meaning of `class` is very different from, say, the Java meaning of `class`).

Comment: I see. Without going through LYAH again, can you sum up how classes and types are different from each other? Also how they compare to classes in an OOP language?

Comment: The answer I wrote above _is_ a description of how classes and types are different from each other. Classes are sets of types that all support some common methods.

Comment: For the case class Eq a => Num a, did you mean to say that Eq is a superset of Num instead of the other way round? As you said, any type in Num must also be in Eq, making Eq a superset.